# How to show the Outlook addin only after installation

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I have developed a Outlook Addin using VSTO in Visual Studio 2010, on Windows XP/SP 3.

1. Build the VSTO solution, and I open Outlook 2010.
2. I see that the Add in has been installed. ( which is strange ).
3. Shut down Outlook.
4. Clean the VSTO solution 5) Open Outlook 2010, the add in is not
   there.

So I believe Outlook understands that an Outlook add in is there, but I dont want the mentioned behaviour.

**What am I looking for :-**

I have created the installer using ClickOnce .

I should only see the Outlook addin , once I have executed the installer.

Any ideas shall be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build a VSTO addin, it gets automatically installed on your development machine.  It is Visual Studio that is doing this for you, to make debugging easyer.

You can probably uninstall your addin automatically by using post-build events, but "Clean project" may be just as easy.

Comment: Thanks GTG. When shipping the VSTO, if I supply the installation files, created by ClickOnce, shall that be okay.

Comment: The behavior you are seeing is not a problem, but of course, there are other potential problems.

Comment: GTG- are you talking of potential problems in developing VSTO, if yes, then I had come across one such on Outlook security, Outlook 2003 addin did not work properly for Outlook 2007.

Comment: No, I'm talking about potential problems with deployment.  I reccommend reading up on that.  The deployment model has gotten much better in VSTO 4, but you still need to tread carefully and test your setup on a typical machine, so you know you don't forget some important dependencies or security settings.  I used Google a lot when I was creating my first VSTO setup :-)

Comment: Microsoft is still experimenting, you can read this article http://sujay-ghosh.blogspot.com/2009/12/develop-office-addins-in-breeze-part-1.html - an excellent tool for developing addins